# FPC TList Specialization not supported

Tags: delphi, generics, lazarus, fpc

I am using Lazarus 1.0.4 with FPC 2.6

I am trying to create a TList of an own class (I just use string here, because it is more easy), but when I try to use

```
type
TStringList = specialize TList<string>;
```

it says "Specialization is only supported for generic types.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Clearly TList is not generic. You are using the class from Classes I guess. In the Delphi RTL you'd use the generic TList from Generics.Collections. Not sure where you find the equivalent in FPC.

Comment: @TLama the string in the Q is just an example. In the real code it is TList<TMyType>

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes, I am. I already tried using Generigc.Collections, but Lazarus said it is an unknown unit.

Comment: which unit does define this class?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you are right. At the moment TList is defined by Classes.

Comment: @TLama as far as I know I would not have to define an own class for my List if i could use Generics.Collections, would I? And in your Post he talks about defining an own generic class.

Comment: What do the docs say? Which unit defines the generic class?

Comment: according to the wiki it's the fgl unit, see http://wiki.freepascal.org/Generics#fgl_unit

Comment: @RoaldvanDoorn yes that seems to work! Thank you everyone for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might as well post it as answer, since it seems to have done the trick.

You need to use the `fgl` unit. See the [Wiki at freepascal.org](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Generics#fgl_unit).